# Snakemake InputFunctionException. AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I have a list object with ChIP-seq single-end fastq file names `allfiles=['/path/file1.fastq','/path/file2.fastq','/path/file3.fastq']` . I'm trying to set that object, `allfiles`, as a wildcard (I want the input of the fastqc rule (and others such as mapping, but let's keep it simple). I tried what is seen in the code below (`lambda wildcards: data.loc[(wildcards.sample),'read1']`). This, however, is giving me the error

```
"InputFunctionException in line 118 of Snakefile:
AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'sample'
Wildcards:
"
```

Does someone know exactly how to define it? It seems I am close, I get the general idea but I am failing to get the syntax correct and execute it. Thank you !

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read in config file parameters
configfile: 'config.yaml'
sampleFile = config['samples'] # three columns: sample ID , /path/to/chipseq_file_SE.fastq , /path/to/chipseq_input.fastq
outputDir = config['outputdir'] # output directory

outDir = outputDir + "/MyExperiment"
qcDir = outDir + "/QC"

# Read in the samples table
data = pd.read_csv(sampleFile, header=0, names=['sample', 'read1', 'inputs']).set_index('sample', drop=False)
samples = data['sample'].unique().tolist() # sample IDs
read1 = data['read1'].unique().tolist() # ChIP-treatment file single-end file
inplist= data['inputs'].unique().tolist() # the ChIP-input files
inplistUni= data['inputs'].unique().tolist() # the ChIP-input files (unique)
allfiles = read1 + inplistUni

# Target rule
rule all:
    input:
        expand(f'{qcDir}' + '/raw/{sample}_fastqc.html', sample=samples),
        expand(f'{qcDir}' + '/raw/{sample}_fastqc.zip', sample=samples),

# fastqc report generation
rule fastqc:
    input: lambda wildcards: data.loc[(wildcards.sample), 'read1']
    output:
        html=expand(f'{qcDir}' + '/raw/{sample}_fastqc.html',sample=samples) ,
        zip=expand(f'{qcDir}' + '/raw/{sample}_fastqc.zip',sample=samples)
    log: expand(f'{logDir}' + '/qc/{sample}_fastqc_raw.log',sample=samples)
    threads: 4
    wrapper: "fastqc {input} 2>> {log}"
```

Comment: Oh. I noticed that I left "wrapper:" instead of changing it to "shell:" (at first I used a fastqc wrapper by Snakemake). I also modified that. (I left it in the original post anyways, in case someone else makes the same mistake, but I corrected it in my code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `output` files of `rule fastqc` doesn't have any wildcards once they are resolved. That is, there is currently one job in the snakefile where `rule fastqc` tries to produce one output file for all samples.

However, it appears you would like to run `rule fastqc` separately for each sample. In that case, it needs to be generalized as below, where `{sample}` is the wildcard:

```py
rule fastqc:
    input: lambda wildcards: data.loc[(wildcards.sample), 'read1']
    output:
        html = qcDir + '/raw/{sample}_fastqc.html,
        zip=qcDir + '/raw/{sample}_fastqc.zip'
    log: logDir + '/qc/{sample}_fastqc_raw.log'
    threads: 4
    shell: "fastqc {input} 2>> {log}"
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the wildcard definition problem! Nevertheless, there's something failing also in the shell part: "MissingOutputException: Job finished but output files are missing. " I substituted the shell command for "wrapper: 0.34.0/bio/fastqc" and the error went away. Maybe because the fastqc shell command doesn't have {output} in there it's not working properly? (and probably in the snakemake wrapper this is taken care of)

Comment: fastqc by default saves output files at the same directory as input files. You may change this behavior by using [`--outdir`](https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastqc/INSTALL.txt).

Comment: it seems to be the problem, yes, but only adding --outdir /path/ for some reason it's not enough to remove this error. Could it be that I have to modify something else? for example, in the target rule ? (all seems fine to me, but who knows... ). I also had a look at the snakemake wrapper code and this person also uses --output but then has to move the files anyways. https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wrappers/fastqc.html looks like or fastqc doesn't move the samples even though I set --outdir , or there's another incompatibility somewhere in the Snakefile

Comment: I would recommend running fastqc command in the terminal and looking closely at the output filenames.